# ChromeDriverService: Builder cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There is a dependency issue when I'm trying to load this code from a sample. Probably the only difference is that I'm using Maven to load the dependencies. I already included the required test libraries and downloaded `chromedriver.exe`.

What else can be missing?

The dependency error below is triggered by the `ChromeDriverService.Builder()`:

`The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

Here the class `ChromeDriverService.Builder()` gets loaded:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void createAndStartService() {
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
    .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("chromedriver.exe"))
        .usingAnyFreePort()
        .build();
    service.start();
}
```

Here are my Maven dependencies for testing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>           
    <version>2.48.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver` as a dependency (I would also recommend making all of your `org.seleniumhq.selenium` dependencies use the same version):

e.g.

```
<properties>
    <selenium.version>2.48.2</selenium.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```